# Differentiate Windows updates important and optional updates

Tags: windows, windows-update

I updated my Windows server and I forgot that my update should be only Important. Not optional.
Now, I want to uninstall the optional update but on my update history, I cannot differentiate which are important and which are optional.
Can you help me?
I have an example below.

```
Update      KB977239
Update      KB2830477
Update      KB2592687
Update      KB981390
Update      KB2574819
Update      KB2685811
Update      KB2685813
Update      KB2719857
Update      KB2726535
Update      KB2732059
Update      KB2750841
Update      KB2761217
Update      KB2763523
Update      KB2791765
Update      KB2800095
Update      KB2808679
Update      KB2843630
Update      KB2852386
Update      KB2853952
Update      KB2857650
Update      KB2891804
Update      KB2893519
Update      KB2908783
Update      KB2919469
Update      KB2966583
Update      KB2970228
Update      KB2985461
Hotfix      KB3006137
Update      KB3020370
Update      KB3054205
Update      KB3054476
Update      KB3068708
Update      KB3078667
Update      KB3080079
Update      KB3080149
Update      KB3092627
Update      KB3102429
Update      KB3107998
Update      KB3121255
Update      KB3133977
Update      KB3137061
Update      KB3140245
Update      KB3147071
Update      KB3172605
Update      KB3179573
Update      KB3181988
Update      KB982018
Update      KB4019265
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you get that list? 
What version of Windows are you running? 
Even on Windows 7, Windows Update gives you a display like this
if you click on the [View update history](https://superuser.com/q/1211492/150988#1211503) link, or go to
`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update\View update history`:

[image: Windows Update → View update history]

Comment: I got it using batch file:
code:
wmic qfe > C:\temp\winupd.txt
exit

Comment: Before installing the opdate, I have only 4 important installed and 45 or so optional installed.
But after the installation, I have a total of 50 or so installed updates..
The thing is , I want to identify among them which is the important and which is not.
the result of the batch file, update history and installed file are quite different.

Comment: @Scott Maybe it would be helpful if you answered your own question... How did *you* get that list?

Comment: @Excellll: Well, I thought I did, at least sort-of; but OK, I’ve added detail.